# R Shiny: Repeated labels in legend for subplots

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

In the legend, I want two plots to share "color1" and "color2" label. Is there a way to do this?

Note: The input value x determines two pairs of values, namely, y1, z1 and y2, z2. Y1 and y2 should share the same color, and z1 and z2 should share the same color.

[image]

```
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("x", "Slider X", min = 3, max = 10, value = 6),
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput(outputId = "plots")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$plots <- renderPlotly({
    
    x<- floor(runif( input$x, min=0, max=10))
    y1<- 2* x
    z1<- (x)^2
    y2<- 1.5* x
    z2<- sqrt(x)
    results <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y1,z1,y2,z2))
    
    plot1 <- ggplot(data=results,aes(x=x))+
      geom_line(aes(y=y1, color="color1"))+
      geom_point(aes(y=y1, color="color1"))+
      geom_line(aes(y=z1, color ="color2"))+
      geom_point(aes(y=z1, color ="color2"))
    
    p1 <- ggplotly(plot1)
    
    plot2 <- ggplot(data=results, aes(x=x))+
      geom_line(aes(y=y2, color="color1"))+
      geom_point(aes(y=y2, color="color1"))+
      geom_line(aes(y=z2, color="color2"))+
      geom_point(aes(y=z2, color="color2"))
    
    p2 <- ggplotly(plot2)
    
    subplot(p1,p2,nrows = 1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `style(showlegend = FALSE)` to hide the legenditems for one of the plots:

```
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
                sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                  sliderInput(
                    "x",
                    "Slider X",
                    min = 3,
                    max = 10,
                    value = 6
                  ),
                ),
                mainPanel(plotlyOutput(outputId = "plots"))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plots <- renderPlotly({
    x <- floor(runif(input$x, min = 0, max = 10))
    y1 <- 2 * x
    z1 <- (x) ^ 2
    y2 <- 1.5 * x
    z2 <- sqrt(x)
    results <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, y1, z1, y2, z2))
    
    plot1 <- ggplot(data = results, aes(x = x)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = y1, color = "color1")) +
      geom_point(aes(y = y1, color = "color1")) +
      geom_line(aes(y = z1, color = "color2")) +
      geom_point(aes(y = z1, color = "color2"))
    
    p1 <- ggplotly(plot1) %>% style(showlegend = FALSE)
    
    plot2 <- ggplot(data = results, aes(x = x)) +
      geom_line(aes(y = y2, color = "color1")) +
      geom_point(aes(y = y2, color = "color1")) +
      geom_line(aes(y = z2, color = "color2")) +
      geom_point(aes(y = z2, color = "color2"))
    
    p2 <- ggplotly(plot2)
    
    subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]